# how to set inter_op_parallelism_threads and intra_op_parallelism_threads for seesion configuration in Tensorflow c++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I know how to set intra and inter threads in python tensorflow which is as shown below

```
n_cpus=1
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
     device_count={ "CPU": n_cpus },
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=n_cpus,
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=8
));
```

But I need to implement this in c++. SO any equivalent code to set inter and intra threads in tensorflow c++ ??

Comment: You can check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13853#issuecomment-588060096) out, it has an example code in the comment, hope this help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in C++ by using the following code.

```
Status LoadGraph(string graph_file_name, std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>* session) {
  tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
  Status load_graph_status =
      ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), graph_file_name, &graph_def);
  if (!load_graph_status.ok()) {
    return tensorflow::errors::NotFound("Failed to load compute graph at '",
                                        graph_file_name, "'");
  }
  
  // initialize the number of worker threads
    tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
    tensorflow::ConfigProto & config = options.config;
    config.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1);
    config.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1);
    config.set_use_per_session_threads(false); 

  session->reset(tensorflow::NewSession(options));
  Status session_create_status = (*session)->Create(graph_def);
  if (!session_create_status.ok()) {
    return session_create_status;
  }

  return Status::OK();
}
```